# Android: how to change color to buttons of AlertDialogFragment

Tags: android, button, colors, android-dialogfragment

I can't find the way to specify a custom text color to the buttons of the AlertDialogFragment.

I have tried with theme and programmatically, but no luck.

Comment: use custom layout for the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a `DialogFragment`, in which I show an `AlertDialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null))
.setPositiveButton(R.string.open_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            ...
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            ...
        }
    });
...
connDialog = builder.create();
connDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button b = connDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            b.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            ...
        }
    });
```

Setting them in `AlertDialog`'s builder didn't help me, either. Try this way.